# hotlink protection compatibility issue with uc browser

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am using this code in cpanel for hotlink protection and its working fine in all browser, except uc browser

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^.]+\.)?domain1\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^.]+\.)?domain2\.net/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Mediapartners-Google|googlebot-image|msnbot|psbot) [NC]           
RewriteRule \.(php|bm|zip|mp4|mkv)$ http://errordomain.com/404.html [R,NC]
</IfModule>
```

uc browser lead me to 404 every time , even from domain1.com and domain2.net. any suggestion

Comment: i have tried with adding an empty refferer  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ but still no solution

Comment: So start by figuring out which referer and UA agent it actually sends then.

Comment: its working fine on every browser except uc desktop browser, while it also working fine on uc mobile browser

Comment: And? Are you saying you are willing to leave it at that now? If not, then what is the point of you telling us that? If you want to find out what the actual problem is, then you need to go and start with some basic debugging.